# SQL create a golden record from information in multiple rows

Tags: sql

For most part SQL is fairly robust and when I hit a dead wall, it is usually my limitation. And this is what I am stuck with today.

What I have in my table ?
[image: What I have in my table ?]

What output should look like ?
[image: What output should look like ?]

What I have got so far ?

```
    WITH tempTable AS (
SELECT
    EID,
    Gender,
    NameLast,
    NameFirst,
    NameMiddle,
    AddrStreet1,
    AddrStreet2,
    City,
    State,
    Zip,
    Country,
    SSN,
    DOB,
    HomePhnAreaCode,
    HomePhnNumber,
    CellPhnAreaCode,
    CellPhnNumber,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EID ORDER BY ModifiedDate DESC) AS RowNum
FROM
    [Database].[dbo].[OriginalTable]
)

UPDATE TABLE [Database].[dbo].[SecondaryTable] SET col1, col2, col3....
SELECT
    EID,
    MAX (Gender)    AS  Gender,
    MAX (NameLast)  AS  NameLast,
    MAX (NameFirst) AS  NameFirst,
    MAX (NameMiddle)    AS  NameMiddle,
    MAX (AddrStreet1)   AS  AddrStreet1,
    MAX (AddrStreet2)   AS  AddrStreet2,
    MAX (City)  AS  City,
    MAX (State) AS  State,
    MAX (Zip)   AS  Zip,
    MAX (Country)   AS  Country,
    MAX (SSN)   AS  SSN,
    MAX (DOB)   AS  DOB,
    MAX (HomePhnAreaCode)   AS  HomePhnAreaCode,
    MAX (HomePhnNumber) AS  HomePhnNumber,
    MAX (CellPhnAreaCode)   AS  CellPhnAreaCode,
    MAX (CellPhnNumber) AS  CellPhnNumber
FROM
    tempTable
GROUP BY
    EID
```

This approach does not seem to work so far.
Can some of you get me the right direction on how this can be done !?

Comment: The 'desired results' seem to come from several rows.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to create one complete record combining information from several rows. The idea is when ever I look up a particular EID, I get the most updated information available.

Comment: Wouldn't the most recent row have all of the most recent information?  If not, I would fix that.  Otherwise, how does your query (or you) know which column was changed when?

Comment: each row comes from a different data source... the only identifier that would recognize the person is the unique EID. So the underline idea is we are trying to create a complete view of demographic details related to each person based on bits and pieces of information from each row.

Comment: I have a sinking feeling a data structure list this is why my doctors office keeps reactivating my address from 3 years ago.

Comment: Sorry about that. We will put some serious thoughts so that we don't do it for others. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83155/discussion-between-jen-r-and-weshall).

Answer (score 0):

if speed is not important, you could try a "naive" approach like this

```
SELECT
(SELECT TOP(1) firstCol FROM YourTable WHERE firstCol IS NOT NULL ORDER BY someCol) AS firstCol,
(SELECT TOP(1) secondCol FROM YourTable WHERE secondCol IS NOT NULL ORDER BY someCol) AS secondCol,
(SELECT TOP(1) thirdCol FROM YourTable WHERE thirdCol IS NOT NULL ORDER BY someCol) AS thirdCol 
...
```

as far as i know, there is no aggregate function that allows you to "choose"/"select" a value with certain properties (like "not null") from a column when using GROUP BY. (plus it wouldn't be an "aggregate" any more)

Comment: Sorry to say whatever we come up with will run daily for 3+ million unique EIDs. The infrastructure team would definitely not be happy.